# which Dia package should I download for ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04

http://dia-installer.de/download/linux.html

Dia Diagram Editor.

Which package should I download and why?

Answer (score 8):

Dia is available from [the official repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/dia), so just install from there:

```
sudo apt-get install dia
```

Or visit [the Ubuntu application catalogue](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dia/).

Answer (score 0):

Amd64 version should compatible with your pc, since you was using 64-bit version of ubuntu.

Type this following command one by one to download dia directly from terminal :

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/files/dia/0.97.2/dia-libs_0.97.2-5_amd64.deb
```

And then install it :

```
cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i dia-libs_0.97.2-5_amd64.deb
```

Note: You also can run 32 bit application on 64-bit platform.